# Google play services lib always shows a red cross in project -> properties -> Android

Tags: android

I am making a GCM project,where in i need to import the Google play services lib.but everytime i add it in properties->Android and try to run it always shows a red cross.....so everytime i have to remove that lib,and again add it all over again..

Am really confused as everytime this is happening,nd i really dont know what is the problem..

Help appreciated
Thanks.[image]

So everytime ders a cross over the lib project and i have to keep to adding it over and over again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325654/can-not-install-google-play-services-into-eclipse-correctly-trying-to-get-maps

Comment: Its still not working for me....